# jQuery create an element with attributes which contain hyphen Unexpected token '-'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to create a button with bootstrap classes like below.

```
$("<button/>",
  {
  type: 'button',
  class:'close',
  data-dismiss: 'alert',
  aria-hidden:'true'}).appendTo("#testt");
```

Since `data-dismiss` has hyphen, it shows  `Unexpected token '-'`.

How to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: 'data-dismiss' try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `data-dismiss` as a string, it will not be a problem

like:

```
$("<button/>", {
  type: 'button',
  class: 'close',
  'data-dismiss': 'alert',
  'aria-hidden': 'true'
}).appendTo("#testt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this.

```js
$("<button/>", {
    type: "button",
    class: "close",
    dataDismiss: "alert",
    ariaHidden: "true",
}).appendTo("#testt");
```